# FileStream - "The given path's format is not supported"

Tags: c#, .net, filestream

I'm trying to use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) to save a spreadsheet on our LAN. I'm using a `FileStream` object to do this, however whenever I attempt to instantiate the object I get the error

`The given path's format is not supported`

**C#**

```
    private static string _fileName = "ErroredRows_";
    private static string _results =
        @"\\prdhilfs03\l&i-sales&mkt\WORKAREA\Agencyservices\Shared\AIC\Analysts_and_Reporting\Realignments\2014\MassUpdateTesting\Results\";

    public static void WriteSpreadsheet(Dictionary<DataRow, string> errors)
    {
        //Create download Destination
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(_results, _fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss") + ".xlsx");

        FileStream newFile = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

        //Construct new Excel package
        ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);

        //Instantiate workbook object
        var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Query1");
```

Here's the contents of the `filePath` `string` variable.

```
\\\\prdhilfs03\\l&i-sales&mkt\\WORKAREA\\Agencyservices\\Shared\\AIC\\Analysts_and_Reporting\\Realignments\\2014\\MassUpdateTesting\\Results\\ErroredRows_2014-01-30_13:46:33.xlsx
```

This line throws the error mentioned above:

```
FileStream newFile = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
```

Comment: You can't have `:` in a filename or path

Comment: Nice :) If you want to place that as an answer will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't have `:` in your filename or path.

What i would do if i were you is this:

```
DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()
```

instead of

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss")
```

Anyway, you can keep your own logic but you have to remove `:` (instead use `-` or `_` for example)