# giving error while creating pdf.The process cannot access the file.because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

im exporting web page div into pdf and sending that mail to pdf. for first time its creating pdf and sending mail properly.but for next time its giving error saying . file is bieng used by a another process at this line

```
 PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(strPath, FileMode.Create));
```

my aspx.cs code is-

```
System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();


                System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
                design.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
                string myText = stringWrite.ToString().Replace("&", "&amp;");
                StringReader sr = new StringReader(myText.ToString());
                Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);

                string strPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\Temp\\WeeklyReport of " + Projname + ".pdf";
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(strPath, FileMode.Create));
                pdfDoc.Open();
                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);

                pdfDoc.Close();
                pdfDoc.Dispose();

                LblNoteMsg.Text = strPath;
                DateTime input = DateTime.Now;
                int delta = DayOfWeek.Monday - input.DayOfWeek;
                DateTime dats = DateTime.Now.AddDays(delta);
                //this week
                DateTime monday = input.AddDays(delta);
                string MonDate = monday.ToShortDateString();
                DateTime sat = monday.AddDays(5);
                string SatDate = sat.ToShortDateString();
                StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/WeeklyMail.txt"));
                string body = r.ReadToEnd();
                MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
                string MailId = txtMailId.Text;
                foreach (string ss in MailId.Split(",".ToCharArray()))
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ss) == false)
                    {
                        Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(ss));
                    }
                }


                Msg.Subject = "Weekly status Report";
                Msg.Body = body;
                Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                Msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(strPath));

                SmtpClient MailServer = new SmtpClient();
                try
                {

                    MailServer.Send(Msg);
```

Comment: Have you tried to assign new FileStream(strPath, FileMode.Create) to a separate varaible and then call either Close() or Dispose() on it when you are done writing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In below code you can add some timestamp to file name so that different files get created.

```
string strPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\Temp\\WeeklyReport of " + Projname + ".pdf";
```

To

```
string strPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\Temp\\WeeklyReport of " + Projname + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:ss") +".pdf";
```

Comment: its giving error if i change the file path name ,The given path's format is not supported.@Nitin Varpe

Comment: Use Path.Combine, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348768/the-given-paths-format-is-not-supported and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468159/filestream-the-given-paths-format-is-not-supported

Comment: D:\may seoapp development\seoapp june 6\\Temp\WeeklyReport of Testing project08-06-2015 10:58:39.pdf ....this is the path its creating @Nitin Varpe

Comment: still same error.

D:\may seoapp development\seoapp june 6\\Temp\WeeklyReport of Testing project08-06-2015_11:03:24.pdf @Nitin Varpe

Comment: Whats error now, file being used or path format incorrect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79916/discussion-between-coder-and-nitin-varpe).

Answer (score 0):

I have changed file name by adding date and time.

```
string strPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\Temp\\WeeklyReport of " + Projname + DateTime.Now.ToString(" dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss") + ".pdf";
```

Answer (score 0):

After sending the email

```
Msg.Attachments.Dispose();
```